# DateTime.Now.Ticks repeating inside a loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate a unique ID for the primary key of a table and I am using `DateTime.Now.Ticks` for it. That's a requirement for now we can't use `Identity`.

But sometimes, within a loop it generates same IDs on consecutive iterations. 
My simplified Code would look like this

```
    While(IncomingData.Next())
    {
     IncomingData.ID = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
     // Other Operations
      .
      .
      .
     InsertInDatabase(IncomingData);
    }
```

Is it because my processor's speed for Instructions/sec is greater than the precision of at which `Ticks` is measured ? 
I am using I5 2.9GHZ Processor. Though I have solved my problem by introducing a count variable and adding it to `ticks`. It Doesn't feel like a good approach. Anyway can someone break it down for me as how does a `tick` is calculated is it dependent on cpu cycle ? Thanks.

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid()` will return a `string` with alphanumeric characters

Comment: unique ID using Ticks it amazing

Comment: Why don't you let the database generate an unique id for you?

Comment: The loop goes faster than the ticks. Use GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) please.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Is it ?

Comment: @Sam i will got with PeterBons comments what kind of requirement it is . using tick for ID.

Comment: you can also seed your id like `id int IDENTITY(9586,1)`

Comment: from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx): "A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds", so it doesn't depend on processor speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case where I see some merit in your strategy is if you need to query your database for data between specific dates. Otherwise a **simple integer counter** - starting from 0 or 1 - will probably always be better.

Your idea is not utterly bad if implemented properly and used the way it is meant to be used. It may just be needlessly complicated.

I am assuming that you want you primary key to be an increasing integer, a sensible requirement to keep your inserts fast with some databases. **A GUID will not work for you**.
I am assuming that you cannot use an auto-incremented database key.
I am also assuming that you will not write into your database from multiple applications - nor multiple computers.

First, you need to take daylight saving into account: use DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now. That's because DateTime.Now can jump backwards in case of daylight saving.

Second, you should expect DateTime.UtcNow to jump backwards anyway in rare occasions - when the system clock is adjusted. It means you need to save the previously allocated value anyway.

Third, as you already know, the precision of the system clock is not infinite - typically it is 15 ms -, so you need to save the previously allocated value and increment it in case DateTime.UtcNow returns the same value twice.

Fourth, knowing that you will need to keep a variable holding the previously allocated value, why not **drop the whole DateTime idea** and rely only on that variable? What I mean is: at the start of your program, you could read the greatest value from the database, store it into your counter in memory and then increment the counter everytime you need a new key value.

Comment: Thankyou very elaborate answer. I will work around my ID generation situation. But I wanted to understand the link between `Ticks` and processor speed. Is there a connection between them or something ?

Comment: Refer to this link for information http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20021111.asp

Comment: @Sam DateTime.Now probably uses the real-time clock, which has no connection with CPU cycle frequency since it must still work when the computer is shut down. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/253719) for more info.

Comment: @Sam Regarding DateTime.Ticks: it is just how DateTime is represented internally, as an integer number of hundreds of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 5):

Using `DateTime.Now.Ticks` as database identity is a very bad idea. Even you resolved the "repeating issue" in your question, your application will probably break in the future, for example, a very common scenario, the application is deployed on multiple servers.

You can either (1) use a database auto-generated, auto-increased id, or (2) use `Guid` to fix the issue.

**EDIT** Under the database performance consideration, auto-increased `long` id has a better performance than guid in most circumstances.

**EDIT** Treat `tick` as an unit of time measurement just like year/month/day/hour/minute/second/millisecond/nanosecond. `Tick` is between millisecond and nanosecond, 1 millisecond = 100000 ticks.

Comment: Guid would return alphanumeric characters ? won't it ?

Comment: @Sam Yes. You need to change the column type in the database.

Comment: A GUID is a terrible primary key with databases that favor sequential primary keys. it will hurt the performance of your inserts as the database will need to move many rows on each insert.

Comment: @ZunTzu Agree. I'll add it into the answer.

Comment: totally agreed with your answer. But mainly i wanted to Understand the working of `Ticks` and how is it related to the hardware(CPU) ?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:

The precision of `DateTime.Now` is around 15ms, if you loop faster than that, `DateTime.Now` will have the same value over differents iterations.

---

As described in the [.Net source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,130):

> The data is stored as an unsigned 64-bit integeter
>
> Bits 01-62: The value of 100-nanosecond ticks where 0 represents 1/1/0001 12:00am, up until the value 12/31/9999 23:59:59.9999999

Furthermore, the [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is quite imprecise:

> The resolution of this property depends on the system timer, which is approximately 15 milliseconds on Windows systems

---

For the ID assignation part, as other stated, use `GUID` which have been made for this purpose.

Comment: The fact that a tick is 100 ns does not mean it is updated at that frequency.  Most of the time it is updated at much slower rate. The rate depends on the hardware available.

Comment: A GUID is a terrible primary key with databases that favor sequential primary keys. It will hurt the performance of your inserts as the database will need to move many rows on each insert.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, DateTime.Now.Ticks value is updated roughly every 15ms on most current computers, even though I've read that it can be updated every 1ms. Anyhow it is a value that needs to be updated by the OS and not directly read from the clock, so getting the same result in two different reads is expectable. I'd suggest that you use a different, as an auto increased value on the database or a GUID.

This articles sheds some light on the matter: http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20021111.asp

Comment: For the record, `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` updates more often (on typical hardware systems) than does `DateTime.Now`. However, it is still a bad idea to assume that `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` is unique.

Comment: A GUID is a terrible primary key with databases that favor sequential primary keys. it will hurt the performance of your inserts as the database will need to move many rows on each insert.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating a unique sequential Id in C#

Creating a unique sequential Id based of DateTime.Now.Ticks is challenging. But can be done if you consider the points in @ZunTzu's excellent answer.

The code below is used by the [Kestrel HTTP server](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/6fde01a825cffc09998d3f8a49464f7fbe40f9c4/src/Kestrel.Core/Internal/Infrastructure/CorrelationIdGenerator.cs). It's used when Kestrel generates request IDs for traces.

```
internal static class CorrelationIdGenerator  
{
    private static readonly string _encode32Chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";

    private static long _lastId = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;

    public static string GetNextId() => GenerateId(Interlocked.Increment(ref _lastId));

    private static unsafe string GenerateId(long id)
    {
        char* charBuffer = stackalloc char[13];

        charBuffer[0] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 60) & 31];
        charBuffer[1] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 55) & 31];
        charBuffer[2] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 50) & 31];
        charBuffer[3] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 45) & 31];
        charBuffer[4] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 40) & 31];
        charBuffer[5] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 35) & 31];
        charBuffer[6] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 30) & 31];
        charBuffer[7] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 25) & 31];
        charBuffer[8] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 20) & 31];
        charBuffer[9] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 15) & 31];
        charBuffer[10] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 10) & 31];
        charBuffer[11] = _encode32Chars[(int)(id >> 5) & 31];
        charBuffer[12] = _encode32Chars[(int)id & 31];

        return new string(charBuffer, 0, 13);
    }
}
```

The key take aways are:

- Use `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` as a 'seed'.
- Use Interlocked.Increment to increment
- In an effort to avoid collisions when called from different machines. You could consider prefixing with the machine name hash (Not perfect but will work for most use cases).

When trying to do this myself for a IoT project I discovered this code when reading [this excellent blog post, aptly named Generating IDs in C# 'safely' and efficiently](https://www.nimaara.com/generating-ids-in-csharp/).

Answer (score -2):

The better approach is use auto-generated Id

but If you want to stick with DataTime Tick option, then you can use this approach that will give you a unique number base on your time.

```
Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

Also, you can use

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

That'll also give you a unique number.

Thanks!

Comment: No, `new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);` does not give a unique number. It gives a new random number __generator__ based on one of only one thousand seeds, the seed being from `000` through `999`. This is not a good solution.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, it all depends on min and max value that we choice for random number.
Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
is the seed value and after that we can use rand.Next(min, max);
we have to decide our max value base on our data. It should be greater than our data for uniqueness.

Comment: True, but you did not mention this in your post. Why not create the random number generator with the zero-argument overload `new Random()`? For the acquisition of the actual numbers, even if you specify `min` and `max` the way you mention, the probability of a "collision", a situation where the numbers yielded are not unique, is still considerable. Addition: [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) says something about the probability.