# DateTime.Now.Ticks gives same tick value

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, datetime

One of my colleague had this issue.Please check the code below

```
    foreach (GridViewRow grv in grvCatalogUpload.Rows)
{
    Label lblVariantName = (Label)grv.FindControl("lblVariantName");
    Label lblDesciption = (Label)grv.FindControl("lblDesciption");

    //...get all controls from grid..//

    ent = new TempVariantMst();


    string fpath = string.Empty;
    string extension = string.Empty;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    fpath = ViewState[vs_DirName].ToString() + "//" + lblImageName.Text;

    extension = Path.GetExtension(fpath);

    string tick = string.Empty;
    tick = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

    //-------------same tick on 3rd,4th iteration---------------------//

    fileName = tick+ extension;

    //-------------same tick on 3rd,4th iteration---------------------//

    logger.ErrorFormat("fpath, Details error:{0}{1} ", Environment.NewLine, fpath);
    logger.ErrorFormat("Server.MapPath(FolderPath + fileName), Details error:{0}{1} ", Environment.NewLine, Server.MapPath("~/" + FolderPath + fileName));
    System.IO.File.Copy(fpath, Server.MapPath("~/" + FolderPath + fileName));

    ent.ImagePath = fileName;
   //...set ent..//

    adminService = new AdminService();
    adminService.InsertTempVariantMst(ent);

}
```

I've seen this same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179897/datetime-now-ticks-repeating-inside-a-loop) but the answers there suggest that the processor speed is fast and thus tick value doesn't change between iterations.

Here we are saving a file and also inserting data in DB which should take more time and so the tick value should be different which is not.Right now as a temporary solution,we've added gridview row index with tick

Comment: Show only the code you are having issue with.  That's a hell of a lot of irrelevant code for somebody to look through.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you want a unique identifier, just use `Guid.NewGuid` instead of using ticks.

Comment: It's not really just that the processor is fast, but a lot of effort goes into making ASP.Net as efficient as possible. I've seen cases where hundreds of records could be iterated with no time difference between them. Sure it looks like you're doing a lot here, but once compiled down the instructions are fairly simple. You can't rely on time differentials between record iterations for any sort of meaningful identifier between records.

Comment: @DarrenYoung whole code is relevant as i wanted to show how much operations i am doing before next iteration

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a GUID instead of `DateTime.Ticks` to get your unique name - otherwise you'll get clashes if the DB code runs faster than expected.

Something like:

```
fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + grv.RowIndex.ToString() + extension;
```

This will give you a guaranteed unique filename.

Comment: GUID is longer than ticks to store and also that's not a solution to my problem..my problem is "ticks are duplicated" and not "what should i use for unique identifier"..ticks+rowindex works well for me..